# What's wrong with my code for functions and arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to apply what I've learnt about functions and arguments so I came up with a code that could calculate the school fee (purely hypothetical)

```
def renting_1(laptop, weeks):
            laptop = 5 * weeks
            if weeks > 10:
                    laptop -= 120
            elif weeks > 5:
                    laptop -= 50
            return laptop

def renting_2(textbooks, number_of_textbooks, weeks):
        textbooks = number_of_textbooks * 20 + (10 * weeks)
        if weeks >= 26:
                textbooks -= (5 * (weeks - 26))
        return textbooks

def school_cost(cost, weeks):
        cost = 200 * weeks
        return cost

def total_cost(weeks, number_of_textbooks):
        return renting_1(weeks) + renting_2(number_of_textbooks, weeks) + school_cost(weeks)

print total_cost(22, 4)
```

and when I run it i recieve this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 22, in <module>
  File "python", line 20, in total_cost
TypeError: renting_1() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Can someone explain and maybe fix the code up so I can analyse what was wrong?

Comment: Why is `laptop` a positional argument for function `renting_1`? Shouldn't it not be there? as you are redefining `laptop` in the function anyways.

Comment: You've given one parameter here...`renting_1(weeks)` Read the error.

Comment: For your functions `renting_1`, `renting_2` and `school_cost`, you added a first argument that should not be there. Remove `laptop`, `textbooks` and `cost` respectively from arguments. This is either a typo or you did not quite understand how arguments work. Also read error message, that one is pretty clear.

Comment: what abccd said. You are returning laptop from the function so it doesn't need to be passed in as an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error you got it seems like some of the arguments are not mandatory for your use case. Either you can remove those arguments or send None for the additional arguments or use optional arguments.

Optional arguments can be added at the last by setting a default value for them like below.

**REFERENCE:** http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html

```
def renting_1(weeks, laptop=None):
    laptop = 5 * weeks
    if weeks > 10:
            laptop -= 120
    elif weeks > 5:
            laptop -= 50
    return laptop

def renting_2(number_of_textbooks, weeks, textbooks=None):
    textbooks = number_of_textbooks * 20 + (10 * weeks)
    if weeks >= 26:
            textbooks -= (5 * (weeks - 26))
    return textbooks

def school_cost(weeks, cost=None):
    cost = 200 * weeks
    return cost

def total_cost(weeks, number_of_textbooks):
    return renting_1(weeks) + renting_2(number_of_textbooks, weeks) + school_cost(weeks)

print total_cost(22, 4)
```

Comment: I don't know what OPs use case is. So, added this just in case.

Comment: Even if a value is passed, it's overwritten

Comment: It's a nice explanation, but not for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what it says " renting_1() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

So you built the renting_1 function to accept 2 arguments, (laptop & weeks) but you called it with only one argument renting_1(weeks). You need to add another value to the function call's arguments for laptop.

Answer (score 0):

`renting_1` is defined to receive 2 arguments `laptop` and `weeks`.

When you use it in `total_cost`, you call it like this: `renting_1(weeks)`
There you pass one argument.

You have this problem with all calls. There's something you are not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define the return value in the parameters.

You especially should not override the parameters that are passed in with calculations on other values

For example, `def renting_1(weeks)` is all you need

Answer (score -1):

In this part of your code, `renting_1(laptop, weeks)` takes 2 arguments and you have only given one.

```
def total_cost(weeks, number_of_textbooks):
        return renting_1(weeks) + renting_2(number_of_textbooks, weeks) + school_cost(weeks)
```

Comment: This explains the problem, not the solution